# Get return object name

Tags: c#

Below is a property:

```
public IMongoCollection<Student> Students
{
    get
    {
        string returnObjectName = ??? ;
        return _database.GetCollection<Student>("Student");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the return type in `returnObjectName`? I mean, I want to get Student object name in `returnObjectName`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Right now I have two issues with the question. 1) ```returnObjectName``` is a string, but never used for anything. I cannot guess what it should contain. 2) I wouldn't know what you mean with 'Student object name'.
Some example values, a better description of what values you expect or what you want to do maybe?

Comment: Are you trying to do this ? `string returnObjectName = typeof(Student).Name;` ?

Comment: Might it be possible that you are looking for the name of your student that is a student propertie ? And in this case `.name` is a solution

Comment: returnObjectName is not even used, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

With C# 6 you can use the `nameof` operator to retrieve the name of a certain type:

```
string returnObjectName = nameof(Student);
```

In this case `Student` is a reference to the class, which provides the advantage of compile-time errors and support for 'refactor rename' operations.

You could also use reflection with `typeof` to achieve the same, e.g. when you can't use C# 6 yet:

```
string returnObjectName = typeof(Student).Name;
```

Please note that  the first (`nameof`) is a compile-time operation and the latter (`typeof`) a run-time operation, which is slightly less performant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that instead writing

```
var students = db.GetCollection<Student>("Student");
```

You want to write

```
var students = db.Students();
```

I would suggest you to utilize extension methods to achieve this. One generic extension and for each of your types an additional one.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IMongoCollection<T> Items<T>(this IMongoDatabase database)
    {
        return database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public static IMongoCollection<Student> Students(this IMongoDatabase database)
    {
        return database.Items<Student>();
    }
}
```

You could use the generic extension like this, if you don't write the type specific extension.

```
var students = db.Items<Student>();
```